# Fix a distorted irrigation box & cover?

Tags: irrigation

Is it possible to fix an irrigation valve box that has become so distorted the lid will no longer fit? I've already tried stomping on the lid to no avail.

The box is an NDS Pro Series. My best recollection is that the lid fit in the spring. Digging it out, even if only on two sides, looks to be a relatively major excavation. Alternatively, it might be possible to reshape the corner. Advice will be most welcome.

Here are a couple of images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don’t use it much, clamp long corner to corner and drop the lid on. If you don’t have the right clamps, a couple of chunks of 2x4 and a windlass setup.

To help it square up, you might soak the ground around the outside with the lid on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The best part is applying horizontal force. I've got a 4' Hi-lift jack that might do the trick. I just need to come up with an anchor for its base. I'll let you know how things turn out.

Comment: As it turned out, I was unable to come up with a satisfactory anchor for the jack. Looks like I'll have to wait 'til spring and try again.

Comment: A jack would work. If you want a picture of what I’m thinking of, please ask.

Comment: I would like to see it. Are you thinking of jacking inside the box?

Comment: Gimme a couple of hours… I was thinking, um, outside the box, but inside is probably a good idea as well.

Comment: A major concern about jacking on the inside is damage to the box, especially by the foot of the jack. It's a flat a couple of inches across trying to fit into a corner with a smallish radius.

Comment: It took a while, but I remembered that the jack can be configured to clamp rather than lift. I put the irrigation system into winter mode yesterday - snow has been forecast. Looks like I have to wait for Spring before I try clamping.